Scheduler stopped working when injecting ILogger in IJob when using Quartz.net
Program.cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
        AppSettings.Init(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        ConfigureLogger().Wait();
        
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .UseWindowsService()
    .Build();

host.Run();

async Task ConfigureLogger()
{
    // Set up Application Insights TelemetryConfiguration
    string appInsightsCS = await ApiHelper.GetAppInsightsConnectionString();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsCS))
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = appInsightsCS;

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", "Extractor")
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Practice Id", AppSettings.Instance.PracticeId)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("Practice Name", AppSettings.Instance.PracticeName)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("PmsType", AppSettings.Instance.PmsType)
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryConfiguration, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Appplication Inssights connection not found");
    }
}

Worker.cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await new MyScheduler().Initiate();
    }
}

MyScheduler
public class MyScheduler
{
    
    public async Task Initiate()
    {
        try
        {
            ScheduleInformation scheduleInfo = await ApiHelper.LoadScheduleInfo();

            if(scheduleInfo != null)
            {
                SharedDataService.PracticeConfigs = scheduleInfo.PracticeConfigs;

                await ScheduleJob(scheduleInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}


public async Task ScheduleJob(ScheduleInformation scheduleInfo)
{
    // Create a scheduler
    IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

    // Define a job
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ExtractionJob>()
        .WithIdentity($"Schedule-{scheduleInfo.Id}", $"JobGroup{scheduleInfo.Id}")
        .Build();

    //set job parameters
    job.JobDataMap.Put("JobParams", scheduleInfo);

    // Define a trigger with the retrieved cron expression
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity($"ScheduleTrigger-{scheduleInfo.Id}", $"TriggerGroup{scheduleInfo.Id}")
        .StartNow()
        .WithCronSchedule(scheduleInfo.CronExpression)
        .Build();

    Log.Information($"Schedule started. Id = {scheduleInfo.Id}");
    
    // Schedule the job with the trigger
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    await scheduler.Start();
}

ExtractionJob
Here when I injected ILogger, then after it has stopped working.
public class ExtractionJob : IJob
{
    readonly AzureHelper _azureHelper;
    readonly ILogger<ExtractionJob> _logger;

    public ExtractionJob(ILogger<ExtractionJob> logger)
    {
        _azureHelper = new AzureHelper();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    { }
}


I think you should observe somewhere an exception saying that the constructor for ExtractionJob cannot be resolved, which is I think due to required DI calls.
Try adding to your app startup following:
builder.Host.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.AddConsole();
    //add your provider of choice
});

Please read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0
